# wordpress website My account (user dashboard ) website page is empty (blank) only shows header

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

i am a beginner and working on developing a website on XAMPP local host and i have a problem with my account page, i am using lisfinity theme and the mentioned page must be created and chosen from theme pages as my account page also from woocommerce>advanced>my account page.

the page worked well before but after a while it opened but empty and the log in and register pages made the same but after deactivating plugins they came back to work, only my account page that refused to show any content and driving me nuts.

hope i can find help, thanks in advance

Comment: Rename plugin folder & check again

Answer (score 0):

You can set permalink again wp-admin > settings > permalinks
and also add follow below Woocommerce standard shortcode on pages as well.
https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/